# Returning from action method with Modelstate.Adderror in throgh ajax form,Validation Summary is not showing erro on partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Please help me if any body is here that why my partial view is not showing validation summary.

Comment: Please show us some relevant code.

Comment: sorry dude i have resolved it.actually i was giving wrong UdateTargetId in ajax form